# Android leaving out permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I have built an app and the whole idea behind building the app is that you can use it without being online. The app is a beach guide and you cant get the internet at some beaches, but I currently have three places, 1, a Google map for each beach, 2, an image gallery for each beach in a WebView and if the user likes, GEO location information relative to other beaches.

All three parts of the app give a message saying “if you go any further you will have to be online and it will cost $$$ with your provider”.

My question is, can I not add the permissions to my manifest and have some kind of if statement in the app to ask the user at the stage of going online for permission, or is this just something I have to write into my description?

Cheers,

Mike.

---

Got that, I just have a dilemma where I don’t want the following scaring people before the app is about to be downloaded.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

But the app will be more fun if it does and some people are into that!

This whole reason for the app is you don’t have to go online. If you want to go online you should go to the mobile website which is 100 times more concise than the app could ever be.
So that’s my dilemma.

This may be something for the boys at Andriod to think about???

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You can not add permission at runtime in your manifest file, So you have to do it at application build time,

You can add some condition statements on which bases you can check the connectivity and give further more functionality to your user..

(This is my personal opinion..)